# Nesting of case-selecting functions

Tags: latex3, expl3

Can case-selecting functions like `\prg_case_int` or `\prg_case_str` be nested? If so I will provide some examples of very weird results I observe with nesting.

REVISION:

I messed up the syntax suggested in the `interface3` document by omitting some of the `<code case>` strings. The revised code of my experiment now works and looks like this:

```
%document name: LaTeX3_interface3.tex
%RN 15/3/2012
%   OBJECTIVE: Nesting case-selecting functions prg_case_str or prg_case_int.
%   REFERENCE: The LaTeX3 Intefaces, 8 Feb 2012 (interface3.pdf), page 38ff.
%   COMMENTS: 
%   (1) on the first attempt failed to define all of the <code case> strings and the whole 
%   thing turned pear shaped
%   (2) the printed messages in the result are not properly formatted but that's due 
%   to my inexperience in LaTeX2 and needs to be addressed seperately.
%=====================================================================================

\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{amsmath,xparse} 
\ExplSyntaxOn 
\NewDocumentCommand{\myCommand}{ m m m } 
{ 
   \prg_case_str:nnn { #1 }
{
    {1a} 
    {
        \prg_case_str:nnn { #2 }
        {
            {2A} %{case 1a:2A\\}
            {
                \prg_case_str:nnn { #3 }
                {
                    {3\alpha}   {case 1a:2A:3\alpha\\}
                    {3\beta}    {case 1a:2A:3\beta\\}
                    {3\gamma}   {case 1a:2A:3\gamma\\}                  
                }
                    {None of 1a:2A: 3\alpha, 3\beta, 3\gamma \\}
            }
            {2B} %{case 1a:2B\\}
            {
                \prg_case_str:nnn { #3 }
                {
                    {3\alpha}   {case 1a:2B:3\alpha\\}
                    {3\beta}    {case 1a:2B:3\beta\\}
                    {3\gamma}   {case 1a:2B:3\gamma\\}                  
                }
                    {None of 1a:2B: 3\alpha, 3\beta, or 3\gamma\\}
            }
            {2C} %{case 1a:2C\\}
            {
                \prg_case_str:nnn { #3 }
                {
                    {3\alpha}   {case 1a:2C:3\alpha\\}
                    {3\beta}    {case 1a:2C:3\beta\\}
                    {3\gamma}   {case 1a:2C:3\gamma\\}                  
                }
                    {None of 1a:2C: 3\alpha, 3\beta, 3\gamma\\}
            }
        } 
            {None of 1a: 2A, 2B, 2C\\}
    }
    {1b} 
    {
        \prg_case_str:nnn { #2 }
        {
            {2A}    {case 1b:2A\\}
            {2B}    {case 1b:2B\\}
            {2C}    {case 1b:2C\\}
        } 
            {None of 1b: 2A, 2B, 2C\\}
    }
    {1c} 
    {
        \prg_case_str:nnn { #2 }
        {
            {2A}    {case 1c:2A\\}
            {2B}    {case 1c:2B\\}
            {2C}    {case 1c:2C\\}
        } 
            {None of 1c: 2A, 2B, 2C\\}
    }
}
    {None of 1a, 1b, 1c\\}
}
%etc. etc.
\ExplSyntaxOff 

\begin{document}

$\myCommand{1a}{2A}{3\alpha}$
$\myCommand{1a}{2B}{3\beta}$
$\myCommand{1a}{2C}{3\gamma}$
$\myCommand{1b}{2A}{3gamma}$
$\myCommand{1b}{2B}{3gamma}$
$\myCommand{1b}{2C}{3gamma}$
$\myCommand{x}{2A}{3gamma}$
$\myCommand{1a}{y}{3gamma}$
$\myCommand{1a}{2C}{3gamma}$
$\myCommand{1b}{2A}{3gamma}$
$\myCommand{z}{2B}{3gamma}$
$\myCommand{1b}{2C}{3gamma}$

\end{document}
```

If I knew how to import the resulting .pdf document I would.

My apologies for starting a wild goose chase. My only excuse is that the LaTeX syntax is quite tricky to get right in the absence of automated editing facilities that would as a minimum generate correct indentations. Perhaps such LaTeX3 editing facilities are already available, if they are I would love to hear about them.

Comment: Of course they can. What are these examples?

Comment: yes please provide them, as always there my be bugs but I'm not aware any offcial restrictions

Comment: Obviously I am doing something very stupid with my syntax here. I'll try to fix it before I ask for more help. Thanks.

Comment: OK, I made it work. I had left out some of the <code case> strings. Would like to send you my code example but it is too big to fit into this COMMENT. Should I make this a new question or what other options do I have to send my code?

Comment: @ReinhardNeuwirth: It seems like you've solved your original problem. As such, I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: I accept your judgement that the subject of nesting case selection functions `... is only relevant to ... an extraordinarily narrow situation ...`. Does closing this question mean it will disappear altogether and not be visible to future visitors?